# Laravel distinct/groupBy and paginate

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a `Certificate` model with the following columns: `code`, `number`, `type`, `date`, `version`, etc.

This certificates can be updated and I wanna track those updates using the `version` column. Basically, I want to keep all the certificates, but on the listing page, I want to show them only once and maybe show that a specific record has x versions and show the last one only.

Ex. (id, code, number, type, date, version)

```
1, x1, num1, internal, 01.01.2020, 1
2, x2, num2, external, 01.03.2020, 1
3, x3, num3, external, 02.03.2020, 1
4, x4, num2, internal, 05.01.2020, 2
```

Basically, the record with number `num2` has a newer version, so the list should display only 3 records, where for the record with the number `num2`, the last record (id 4) will be shown.

In the end, these records could be a lot, so I wanna paginate them.

What would be the best/efficient way of achieving this?

I know there are a lot of discussion about the `groupBy` which I was also thing first, but seems like `groupBy` is not an option for my case, but only when trying to group by aggregate values only (count, date, max, etc).

A second option I've found is using `distinct` method which I find it `almost there` and I say this because I wasn't able to filter by a single column and also show the rest of the columns.

Ex:

```
$certificates = Certificate::select('number', 'type', 'code', 'date')->distinct('number')->get(); 
// will display the duplicates too.


$certificates = Certificate::select('number')->distinct('number')->get(); 
//returns the correct records (withoud duplicates) but I lose the access to other (code, type... ) columns.
```

Please note that this should stay as a Query Builder/Eloquent to be able to use the pagination, so I think conveting to a collection is not ok.

Or is there another better solution to achieve this behavior?

Comment: I think, you need to move version in `CertificateVersion` model - this solve all your problems and be much transparent.

Comment: You're right @Maksim .. it will require some adjustments indeed, but in the end I can do everything I mention and I'll have even more control over it. I think I'll go on with this approach. Thank you